# Entity Framework Encrypt Connection String

Tags: entity-framework, encryption

I use Entity Framework and Linq to Entities. I want to encrypt the connection string and the EF has to decrypt automaticaly, How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Javier P. de Jorge

Comment: Is this a web app? ASP.NET has web.config encryption built in.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it or all is automatic even with the EF in the middle.

Comment: ASP.NET web.config encryption "just works." The EF won't care about it.

Answer (score 9):

Use aspnet_regiis. In command line browse to (usually):

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

and type:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "sectionName of web.config" "path" - to encrypt
aspnet_regiis -pdf "sectionName of web.config" "path" - to decrypt
```

For example:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\projects\HelloWorldProject"
```

You don't need to do anything to make L2SQL read ecrypted connection string file.