# how to encrypt decrypt connection string and assign it to Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, encryption, entity-framework-4

I have a asp.net forms website which uses entity Framework.
I need to encrypt the connection string in the web config so that it is not visible to people.
I also need to decrypt the connection string for entity framework to use it.

I am following this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The did run the command `aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Projects\students\exams.UI"` which generated replaced my original connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="StudentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StudentModel.csdl|res://*/StudentModel.ssdl|res://*/StudentModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Server;initial catalog=Student;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

with the following connection string

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>aXfgsT4DI=</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>eCAX0N2hgsldWCTr</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I use the following  code to get the decrypt key back

```
 Dim setting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings


            Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = _
              WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath)
            Dim key As MachineKeySection = CType(config.GetSection("system.web/machineKey"), MachineKeySection)

            DecryptionKey = key.DecryptionKey
            ValidationKey = key.ValidationKey
```

**how do I decrypt get the connection string  settings and assign it to Entity Framework.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Encrypt Connection String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335413/entity-framework-encrypt-connection-string)

Comment: The framework will take care of the decrypting at runtime when you encrypt the web.config file.